# CakePhp 3 link with parameter and extension

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I need create a link with a parameter and .pdf extension, however nothing from older versions of CakePHP seem to work. Ideally it would be a postlink, but html link would be good as well.

Here is where I got so far.

```
//Html link
$this->Html->link('PDF', [ 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'pdf', $user['id'], 'ext' => 'pdf' ]);


//Form postLink
$this->Form->postLink('PDF', [ 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'pdf', $user['id'], 'ext' => 'pdf' ]);
```

The Html link results in: `.../users/pdf/2?ext=pdf` which then is not routed to the pdf template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this...

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#router

Most probably you need to add it as `_ext`